# Compare lists in dataframes based on personal code, shorten one lists if longer

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two separate dataframes each for one speaker of an interacting dyad. They have different amounts of talk-turns (rows) which is why I keep them in separate files for now.

In order to run my final analyses I need identical number of rows for each speaker.

So what I want to do is compare dyad_id 1 in both data frames and then shorten the longer list for one by deleting the last row for all columns.

I prepared a data frame to illustrate what I already have.

So far, I tried to split the data frame by the dyad_id in both data sets to now compare the splits one after another and delete the unnecessary rows. As I have various conversations, I need to automate this to go through all dyad_ids one after another.

I hope someone can help me, I am completely lost.

```
dyad_id_A <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)
fw_quantiles_a <- c(4,3,1,2,3,2,4,1,4,5,6,7)
df_A<- data.frame(dyad_id_A,fw_quantiles_a)


dyad_id_B <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
fw_quantiles_b <- c(3,1,2,1,2,4,1,3,3,4,5)
df_B <- data.frame(dyad_id_B,fw_quantiles_b)
```

## example for final dataset

```
dyad_id_AB <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
```

## What I tried so far:

```
split_conv_A = split(df_A, list(df_A$dyad_id_A))
split_conv_B = split(df_B, list(df_B$dyad_id_B))
```

Comment: Try `rep(rle(dyad_id_A)$values, pmin(rle(dyad_id_A)$lengths, rle(dyad_id_B)$lengths))`

Comment: This will identify the correct number of indentical items within the compared columns which is great already - the major concern is deleting the complete row when one of the columns is longer not just one element in the road.

Answer (score 3):

Add a `time` counter within each `dyad_id_x` group and then `merge` together:

```
df_A$time <- ave(df_A$dyad_id_A, df_A$dyad_id_A, FUN=seq_along)
df_B$time <- ave(df_B$dyad_id_B, df_B$dyad_id_B, FUN=seq_along)

merge(
  df_A, df_B,
  by.x=c("dyad_id_A","time"), by.y=c("dyad_id_B","time")
)
#   dyad_id_A time fw_quantiles_a fw_quantiles_b
#1          1    1              4              3
#2          1    2              3              1
#3          1    3              1              2
#4          2    1              2              2
#5          2    2              3              4
#6          2    3              2              1
#7          3    1              1              3
#8          3    2              4              3
#9          3    3              5              4
#10         3    4              6              5
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you. There is just one issue with the solution - my time variable has values up to 80 and the original sequencing is essential to the following analyses. If I merge the files, the time variable is now sorted as follows: 1, 10,11,12 etc. - Is there a way to keep it at 1,2,3,4,5,etc? If that is sorted out, I am good to go :)

Comment: @LenaMüller - sounds like your `time` variables are characters. Just wrap them to make sure they are numeric when created - `df_A$time <- as.numeric(ave(df_A$dyad_id_A, df_A$dyad_id_A, FUN=seq_along))`

Comment: Hmm, I checked and they were numeric and even if I use as.numeric(ave...), the values in my column are still ordered as 1,10,11,12... Any idea what this could be and how I can fix it?

Comment: @LenaMüller - hmmm, I see what you mean - you could just order your output dataset afterwards - `out[order(out$dyad_id_A, out$time),]`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we can try using `table` to calculate frequncies of id's in both the dataframe assuming you have the same id's in both the dataframe. Calculate the minimum between them using `pmin` and repeat the `names` based on the frequency.

```
tab <- pmin(table(df_A$dyad_id_A), table(df_B$dyad_id_B))
as.integer(rep(names(tab), tab))
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
```